# How to dynamically select template directory to be used in flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

By default Flask uses template files stored in the "templates" directory:

```
/flaskapp
    /application.py
    /templates
        /hello.html
```

Is there any way to dynamically choose a template directory according to the logged-in user?

This is how I want the directory structure to be:

```
/flaskapp
    /application.py
    /templates (default template goes here)
        /hello.html
    /userdata
        /user1
            /template1
                 hello.html
            /template2
                 hello.html
        /user2
            /template1
                 hello.html
            /template2
                 hello.html
```

Now if I have the username of the logged-in user and the name of the template activated by the user, is it possible to dynamically select the directory to load template files from?

For example:

```
/userdata/<username>/<activated template name>/
```

Instead of fixed:

```
/templates/
```

What I am trying to achieve is a WordPress-like theme system for my web application where users can upload/select themes for their website.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is also the possibility to overwrite Jinja loader and set the paths where Jinja will look for the templates. Like:

```
my_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([
        app.jinja_loader,
        jinja2.FileSystemLoader(['/flaskapp/userdata', 
                                 '/flaskapp/templates']),
    ])
app.jinja_loader = my_loader
```

Directories are arranged in the order where Jinja needs to first start looking for it. Then from the view you can render user specific template like this:

```
render_template('%s/template1/hello.html' % username)
```

where username you can dinamically change in the view. Of course you can also there choose which template (1 or 2) to render. But basically what you really miss is this custom Jinja loader with the custom paths.

Hope that helped or gave the ideas :)

Comment: You don't have to escape newlines in Python inside lists or dicts declarations.

Comment: In case anyone is having problems: this doesn't work in Heroku. You have to pass the path without the first `/` (like `'flaskapp/userdata'`).

Comment: Exclude the `app.jinja_loader` line to use only the two folders mentioned

Comment: Thanks this works. I would like to suggest an edit here: When you write this code, Flask will still look into default 'templates' folder but will look into the newly added folder as well.

Answer (score 113):

You can pass the Flask constructor a "template_folder" argument.

Like so...

```
Flask(__name__, template_folder="wherever")
```

Here's the documentation:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/

Comment: And also if you are going to use blueprints, they also can have custom template dir too.

Comment: @IgnasButėnas Using blueprints doesn't work either with two different paths, but `render_template` same template name

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Python, but I have already faced with this problem. I don't know if my solution is right, but it works:

First of all you have to create module for each user

```
/flaskapp
    /application.py
    /templates (default template goes here)
        __init__.py     # default module flaskapp
        views.py        # here you can define methods for default module (like Action in MVC)
        /hello.html
    /static
    /userdata
        /user1
            __init__.py # user1 module
            views.py    # here you can define methods for user1 module
            /template1
                 hello.html
            /template2
                 hello.html
        /user2
            __init__.py # user2 module
            views.py    # here you can define methods for user2 module
            /template1
                 hello.html
            /template2
                 hello.html
```

in application.py init Flask app, add global method render_page_from and register blueprints

```
app = Flask(__name__)
def render_page_from(controller_name, template_name_or_list, **context):
    # here you can choose any controller or use default
    app.jinja_loader.searchpath.clear()
    blueprint = app.blueprints[controller_name]
    app.jinja_loader.searchpath.append(blueprint.template_folder)
    return render_template(template_name_or_list, context=context)

from flaskapp.user1 import controller as user1_controller
from flaskapp.user2 import controller as user2_controller

app.register_blueprint(user1_controller)
app.register_blueprint(user2_controller)
```

in each module (user1, user2 etc) init blueprint in **init**.py

```
templates_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')

controller = Blueprint('user1', __name__, url_prefix='/user1', template_folder = templates_folder)

import flaskapp.user1.views
```

finally add view (action) methods to views.py like this

```
from LocalHub.client import controller
@controller.route('/hello')
def hello():
    """Renders the page"""
    return render_page_from(controller.name, 'hello.html', title='hello')
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it prints out correct search path but render wrong template.