# Flask : How to serve static files from template directory?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am developing a SAAS application using Flask and I want users to be able to create/upload/use their own custom templates. This is how my directory structure is right now :

```
/flaskapp
    /application.py
    /static
        /style.css
    /templates (site & admin templates goes here)
        /hello.html
    /userdata
        /user1
            /template1
                 hello.html
            /template2
                 hello.html
        /user2
            /template1
                 hello.html
            /template2
                 hello.html
```

I am able to serve user specified templates using a solution found through this stackoverflow question : [How to dynamically select template directory to be used in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598363/how-to-dynamically-select-template-directory-to-be-used-in-flask) but how do I serve static files from template directory. Instead of serving static files from `/flaskapp/static/` I want to serve static files using `/flaskapp/userdata/<user>/<current-template>/static/` directory where  and  will be determined dynamically at run time. How to do this?

Comment: When you say `/flaskapp/something` do you mean URLs or directory names? Please say both every time: serve this URL with static files in that directory. Otherwise I just don’t know what you mean.

Comment: By `/flaskapp/something` here I mean directory and not URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using a web server in front of Flask. One way to solve this (which I generally use when using Apache + mod_wsgi for custom WSGI apps) is to just serve the directory straight from disk via the web server. On Apache, I just use an Alias directive for this.

If you want to vary the file served under a given URL per user, you would have to pipe the file through Flask. You'd have to figure out how to properly route the request; after that, you might be able to use [wsgi.file_wrapper](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#optional-platform-specific-file-handling) to send the correct file (though I'm not sure how you'd get at this through Flask).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to serve files from whatever system directory.

The app searches a specific directory for a specific requested file:

when someone accesses **http:/host/where/to/serve/files/example_file.txt** the application will try to return **example_file.txt** as attachment, if the file doesn't exist it will return a 404.

You can adjust this and build the DIRECTORY_TO_SERVE_PATH with your user variables.

You should also validate the files to serve if you have any restrictions because **this returns any file that exists in the path**.

```
import os
from flask import abort, send_from_directory


DIRECTORY_TO_SERVE_PATH = '/where/files/are/in/disk/'


@app.route('/where/to/serve/files/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    if os.path.exists(DIRECTORY_TO_SERVE_PATH + filename):
        return send_from_directory(DIRECTORY_TO_SERVE_PATH, filename, as_attachment=True)
    else:
        abort(404)
```