# call render_template method for a directory outside running app

Tags: templates, flask, directory, jinja2

I'm trying to call the render_template method in flask to a template that is outside the current running directory

```
return render_template('../show_data.html',data=data)
```

You'll notice I tried to use '..' to go back in the directory structure but that is not working as I'm getting a error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
```

Answer (score 6):

By default flask application looks for `templates` folder which located in same directory with application file. But if you want to change it:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='folder/to/template')
```

Or you can use blueprints to have separate template folder

```
main = Blueprint(__name__, 'main', template_folder='folder/to/template')
```

So the problem you are having because of this. Or maybe you can check here [jinja loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598839/5802335)

Comment: once I add the template_folder how would i reference it from the render_template method ?

Comment: Just you need to write template name for example `show_data.html`